I am flying from Philippines to UK and I only have UK visa. I am cruising from UK port and the itinerary includes Norway. Is my UK visa enough?
I am flying from Philippines to UK and I only have UK visa. I am cruising from UK port and the itineraries include Norway and Ireland. Is my UK visa enough to cruise on the ship?

Jamie Pleo, are you going to work on that cruise boat, are you a family member of someone in the crew or are you just going to be a tourist?

If you’re travelling as a passenger/tourist, your UK visa won’t suffice for Norway. Is Ireland the first port after leaving the UK?

Where you need a Visa for depends on your nationality. If you're from the Philippines and have no other nationality then you will need a visa for Norway, Ireland may be covered by the UK visa.
